# Extjs 4 Border Layout with vertical tabs in east region

Tags: extjs, extjs4

is ist possible in ext js 4 to have a east region in a border layout with multiple tabs?
[image]

Thx for your help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?137711-Vertical-Tabs-in-ExtJS4-Ext.ux.tab.VerticalPanel

You should then just be able to assign the panel to the east region, and voila!

Comment: thought about that already. But I'd stil have the menu bars from both. East region and tab panel. I'd rather like to replace the bar from the east region with tabs. Is it posible to have the vertical tabs rotated 90°?

Comment: Not out of the box anymore I don't think, you'd need something custom for that. Menu bars from both? I'm not sure I follow there?

Comment: If I but the tab panel in the east region (which is expandable) I have the label of the region (either as a label bar at the top or if the east region is minified i have it as a vertical menu label). If I put the tab panel within the east region the tabs are hidden when the region is minified. So somehow the tab menu bar must replace the minified menu bar of the east region? My english is not perfect. I hope it becomes clearer what I mean?

Comment: Ahh yes now I understand better. You want want the tabs to occupy the title and still show up when collapsed. Interesting idea though I'm afraid you'd probably have to hack around with the controls.

Comment: Yes gonna try and fool around a little bit

Comment: It's definitely not straight-forward. Panel collapsing uses a `placeholder` header that is shown in place of the standard header. You can set `collapseMode` to `header` then the original header is kept when collapsing, but animation is broken (4.1.1 - see http://tinyurl.com/98r6z6f). 
Look at `Ext.header.Header` to see how they implement a vertical title component using `Ext.draw.Component`.
Sounds like a lot of fun! :)